# Declarative Pipeline - Use of when condition, how to do nested conditions anyOf/allOf/not

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am stuck at how to properly use nested conditions as proposed in the Jenkins syntax.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

This is my current stage:

```
stage('Build'){
when{
    anyOf{
        allOf{
            expression{env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master'}
            expression{env.AUTO_BUILD == true && env.BUILD_OPT == snapshot && env.BRANCH_NAME !=~ /feature.+/} 
        }
        expression{env.AUTO_BUILD == false}
    }
}
steps{
    echo env.AUTO_BUILD
    echo env.BUILD_OPT
    echo env.BRANCH_NAME
}
```

From my point of understanding is, if I set `env.AUTO_BUILD = false`, then this stage should be executed, since it is enclosed in an `anyOf` OR it would execute if my branch was e.g. `develop` and `AUTO_BUILD = true, BUILD_OPT = snapshot`. 
However, this was not the case when I set `AUTO_BUILD = false`. The stage was not executed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just a quick check: you are setting the `env.AUTO_BUILD` to a boolean `false` and not a string `false`, correct?

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that the value was not a boolean when using a booleanParam.

Comment: Does it work now, or are the conditionals still not behaving as you expect?

Comment: The second expression is not working as expected when ´AUTO_BUILD = true´, and ´BUILD_OPT = snapshot´, and ´BRANCH_NAME = feature/testpipeline´ it should skip. But this probably because my groovy regex is incorrect.

Comment: I would agree with that since `!=~` is not a valid operator for "does not match" in Groovy. You should try `!(env.BRANCH_NAME =~ /feature/)` instead (note I also removed the unnecessary `.+` here as that would result already).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Works like a charm :)

Comment: So are nested conditionals possible as you initially proposed? ie. `anyOf{ allOf { ... } ... }`

Comment: It appears so! "*More complex conditional structures can be built using the nesting conditions: not, allOf, or anyOf. Nesting conditions may be nested to any arbitrary depth.*" https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two issues here in the declarative conditionals. First, looking at:

```
allOf {
  expression{env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master'}
  expression{env.AUTO_BUILD == true && env.BUILD_OPT == snapshot && env.BRANCH_NAME !=~ /feature.+/} 
}
```

the issue here is that `!=~` is not a valid operator for "does not match regular expression" in Groovy. You can replace it with `!(env.BRANCH_NAME =~ /feature/)` like so:

```
allOf {
  expression{env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master'}
  expression{env.AUTO_BUILD == true && env.BUILD_OPT == snapshot && !(env.BRANCH_NAME =~ /feature/)} 
}
```

to achieve the behavior you desire.

Secondly, in the conditional:

```
expression{env.AUTO_BUILD == false}
```

the expression is checking for a boolean type in `env.AUTO_BUILD`. If the value is being assigned a string `'false'`, then the type check will fail and the conditional will not behave as expected. Inputting the environment `env.AUTO_BUILD` assignment as a boolean `env.AUTO_BUILD = false` and not a string `env.AUTO_BUILD = 'false'` will rectify this for you.